# How to parse nested json encoded array inside array WITHOUT KEY NAME in android using json method?

Tags: android, json, android-studio, jsonparser

I am trying to fetch the values from php using json parser, but i had stucked in nested array while parsing,
when i try to fetch the image url which is nested,it is converted as one whole string, and it is also in different format, [not in url format].
I had tried all stack overflow examples, but i cannot find a solution for it. Pls. help me to fix this issue.

JSON

```
    {
    "result_data": [
        {
            "images": [
                "uploads/news_feeds/08_01_2020/news_080120201201140.png",
                "uploads/news_feeds/08_01_2020/news_080120201201141.png"
            ],
            "videos": [],
            "audios": [],
            "title": "test1",
            "description": "test"
        },
        {
            "images": [],
            "videos": [],
            "audios": [],
            "title": "test3",
            "description": "test333333333333"
        },
        {
            "images": [],
            "videos": [],
            "audios": [],
            "title": "test5",
            "description": "test55555555555555555555"
        },
        {
            "images": [],
            "videos": [],
            "audios": [],
            "title": "aasa",
            "description": "asdsadasdad"
        }
    ],
    "result_message": "success",
    "result_status": 1
}
```

My code which i treid

```
   protected void onPostExecute(String Image_result) {

        String Title;
        String Description;
        JSONArray Images = null;
        String Audios;
        String Videos;

        JSONObject jsonObjects = null;
        try {
            jsonObjects = new JSONObject(Image_result);
            jsonArray_New = jsonObjects.getJSONArray("result_data");

            if(jsonArray_New!=null){
                try
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray_New.length(); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray_New.getJSONObject(i);

                        Images = jsonObject.getJSONArray("images");

                        for (int j = 0; j < Images.length(); j++)
                        {

                            JSONObject imgObjects = Images.getJSONObject(j);
                            Imagess[j] = imgObjects.getString( "" );

                            Log.d(" Imagess[j]" , "" +  Imagess[j] );
                            Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this , "res" + Imagess[j] ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

                        }



                        //Videos = jsonObject.getString("videos");
                        Title = jsonObject.getString("title");
                        Description = jsonObject.getString("description");
                        //Audios = jsonObject.getString("audios");
                        Log.d("printjs" , "" + Images );
                        Log.d("printjs" , "" + Title );

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Title is fetching correctly, but in images part it is fetching but it is showing type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject as error in logcat.

I dont know this is a correct way to parse the json, any one help me to fix this issue.

Logcat

```
01-09 02:26:53.789 19670-19670/com.example.myapplication W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value uploads/news_feeds/08_01_2020/news_080120201201140.png at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-09 02:26:53.791 19670-19670/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
01-09 02:26:53.791 19670-19670/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:514)
01-09 02:26:53.791 19670-19670/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$Image_data.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:99)
01-09 02:26:53.791 19670-19670/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$Image_data.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:41)
01-09 02:26:53.791 19670-19670/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
01-09 02:26:53.791 19670-19670/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
01-09 02:26:53.791 19670-19670/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
01-09 02:26:53.792 19670-19670/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
01-09 02:26:53.792 19670-19670/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
01-09 02:26:53.792 19670-19670/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
01-09 02:26:53.792 19670-19670/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 02:26:53.792 19670-19670/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-09 02:26:53.792 19670-19670/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
01-09 02:26:53.792 19670-19670/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
01-09 02:26:53.793 19670-19670/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in your inner for-loop where you are grabbing the images `JSONObject imgObjects = Images.getJSONObject(j);`. Here's your fix:

```
for (int j = 0; j < Images.length(); j++)
{
      // remove these lines:
      // JSONObject imgObjects = Images.getJSONObject(j);
      // Imagess[j] = imgObjects.getString( "" );

      // add this line instead
      Imagess[j] = Images.getString(j);

      Log.d(" Imagess[j]" , "" +  Imagess[j] );
      Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this , "res" + Imagess[j] ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

 }
```

Comment: app. is getting crashed and due to null exception value showing in this line Imagess[j] = Images.getString(j);